# How to cover a sticky footer with another element?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a footer that is stuck to the bottom (it stays at the bottom with long pages and short pages.) Here is the css for it

```css
.footer{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;


}
```

I want to create a 'reveal' or curtain effect similar to what is on this website... dartlang.org. (scroll to the bottom obviously). I have tried doing this with a fixed footer but i can't seem to get it to work.

I'm using rails and rendering the footer with this code in my application.html.erb file

```css
<%= render 'shared/footer' unless @disable_footer %>
```

for some reason the jquery reveal footer doesn't want to work with this setup either

EDIT:
here is the code for my footer... its kind of sloppy, sorry.

```css
<footer class="footer" id="#myfooter">
  <body>
  <div style="background-color: white;">
  <hr style="width: 100%;">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h4>Consulting and Development</h4>
          <ul style="font-weight: bold;">


          <li><%= link_to "Training and Coaching", training_coaching_path%></li>
         <li> <%= link_to "Business Development", business_development_path%></li>
         <li> <%= link_to "Automotive Consulting", automotive_consulting_path%></li>
         <li> <%= link_to "Environmental Consulting", environmental_safety_path%></li>

          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h4>Quality Product Assurance</h4>
          <ul style="font-weight: bold;">
            <li><%= link_to "Product Inspection and Quality Resolution", containment_and_quality_path%></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Auditing", auditing_path%></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>


    <hr>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h4 style="text-decoration: underline;">Corporate Office Location:</h4>
        <p>1</p>
        <p></p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h4 style="text-decoration: underline;">Mailing Address:</h4>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
      </div>


      <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center">
        <p>
         <a href="mailto:hr"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="false"></i></a>
          <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x" aria-hidden="false"></i></a>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="false"></i></a>
        </p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <p class="text-muted" style="text-align: center;"> - Copyright 2016 - All Rights Reserved</p>
        <p class="text-muted" style="text-align: center;"> Homepage background image was <a href="http://www.freepik.com/free-vector/gear-icons-collection_792514.htm">Designed by Freepik</a></p>
      </div>



    </div>


  </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a footer with a `position: fixed` and with a lower `z-index` than the main content. Make sure your main-content has the same margin-bottom value than the footer's height in order to see it.

```css
    html,
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .main-content {
      background-color: #333333;
      width: 100%;
      height: 800px;
      margin-bottom: 300px;
    }
    .footer {
      background-color: #0072C6;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 300px;
      z-index: -1;
    }
    .footer p {
      color: #000000;
    }
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras sagittis congue malesuada. Donec a eros ac risus facilisis pellentesque sit amet feugiat orci. Ut adipiscing, arcu sit amet facilisis condimentum, diam arcu tempus erat, at sagittis libero.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras sagittis congue malesuada. Donec a eros ac risus facilisis pellentesque sit amet feugiat orci. Ut adipiscing, arcu sit amet facilisis condimentum, diam arcu tempus erat, at sagittis libero.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras sagittis congue malesuada. Donec a eros ac risus facilisis pellentesque sit amet feugiat orci. Ut adipiscing, arcu sit amet facilisis condimentum, diam arcu tempus erat, at sagittis libero.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: ah, thanks. I was missing the margin on the main content

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by setting `position: relative` and a `z-index` on the main page content element, then by setting a lower z-index on your footer component (which should be set to `position: fixed` rather than `position: absolute`).

e.g.

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-bottom: 100px; /* Must be equal to footer height */
}
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

I knocked up a simple demo here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/reXdby.

Comment: I have tried this, but for some reason it is cutting off the majority of the footer... i'll update my question with the footer code

Comment: Give your main content a bottom margin equal to the height of the footer.  I've updated my answer and 'Pen.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes when you want to see how works a css style of specific web you just use the web browser dev tools (F12) select the button for pick a Dom Element on the page and track the css style, for example the code that belong of your example page have a div with the next class:

```
.footer {
background:#3f4245 url(../imgs/footer-bg.png) repeat-x left top;
padding-top:60px;
padding-bottom:80px;
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
left:0;
z-index:100;
height:300px;
-webkit-transform:translateZ(0)}
```

perhaps this help you for track others css styles in the future, regards.